# Cannot execute Binary file on Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

Here is a repo that I am trying to clone.

https://bitbucket.org/sivareddyg/hindi-part-of-speech-tagger

It says, we support UNIX based system. So I tried running 
"make tag" on OSX terminal.

But it gives this error:

```
/bin/sh: ./bin/tnt: cannot execute binary file
```

I saw some of the answers previously asked on superuser but weren't helpful.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the Bitbucket page says they support "UNIX", but I think they really mean just Linux.  The `make` script needs to run their included `bin/tnt` program.  Running `file bin/tnt` shows:

```
tnt: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
```

For comparison, a "normal" Mac OS X UNIX command (like `man`) returns this:

```
/usr/bin/man: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Conclusion: the bundled `tnt` program is not Mac-compatible.

Workaround 1: Download/compile a Mac version of `tnt`?  Given what you're trying to accomlish, I'm guessing this is the TNT homepage: http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/tnt/

But, they don't make it easy to get the source code, so I'm not sure how lucky you'll be trying that path.

Workaround 2: Get or borrow a Linux computer.